# Unity Scope doesn't search contacs

Tags: unity, 13.04, contacts, scopes

I migrated from Gnome 3.x to Unity, the one thing I miss is the contact search from Gnome.

Mine online contacts Google and Facebook are successful synced with online accounts. When I looked in Gnome contacts there was nothing synced?

Also I can not use Unity Dash to search my contacts. Anyone with an solution?

Sorry for the mediocre English its not my mother tongue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no Unity scope installed by default that will search your contacts.

There is a prototype scope that could fill that role if it is completed here:

https://launchpad.net/unity-lens-people

It isn't really ready for prime time yet though, so is not in the Ubuntu archive.